# If my Gmail address is abcdefgh@gmail.com, then what would be my OpenID?

Tags: passwords, gmail, authentication, openid

If my email is **abcdefgh@gmail.com**, what would be my OpenID?

Comment: Though @jtimberman pointed out that nowadays Gmail addresses must be at least 5 characters, the above email address does in fact exist: `552-5.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota`. Probably due to spam, maybe harvested through examples like these. Please don't post other people's email addresses on the web. (Though not suitable for *this* question, see http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc2606 about using example.com/net/org next time.)

Comment: @alex, if so, couldn't you have provided a link?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you put the link in an *answer* (to get rep for it? ;)

Comment: This question is more clearly formulated than http://superuser.com/questions/35646/what-is-openid-url-for-a-account though. This is clearly Google-specific, while the other one is more unclear (and its answers cover slightly different things).

Comment: @Jonik My plan is foiled! Made my answer community wiki :)

Answer (score 10):

There's a lot of other questions answering this.
Searching for openid would have helped you to find them easily.

Anyway, the google openid is **www.google.com/accounts/o8/id**

<s>An advice, remove the plain text reference of your email address so that it won't be picked up by robots crawling the web.</s>

Comment: Thats not a valid gmail address because gmail requires 5+ characters.

Comment: @jtimberman good point.

Comment: what, doesn't the openid depend on my login? is it the same for all users?

Comment: @x-x not for the google one. The other ones work differently.

Comment: According to http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/10/moving-another-step-closer-to-single.html this is for *if you feel really geeky*, so may be temporary.

Comment: It is the same, because it uses magical google trickery to be unique to you. Magic!

Comment: Sir, every time I forget that URL, it takes me at least 15 minutes roaming around on Google, finding everything in the world there is to know about OpenID, *except* the Google OpenID URL. ;) So thanks, but simply searching for it usually takes some time.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking over this thread on superuser.com: [What is OpenId URL for a account](https://superuser.com/questions/35646/what-is-openid-url-for-a-account). As **dex** pointed out, the answer is `www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`